# 1981 gs 550 suzuki

Tags: suzuki

I have four carbs on rails on my Suzuki GS550. I'm struggling to find out what model these are from Mikuni.

All I can find from markings is "mikuni corporation" on top of the carbs.

Any info would be appreciated

Comment: pictures of the carb would help.. Have you got them off the engine? As there are usually some numbers somewhere...

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!